# Beep or make a sound upon Cut, Copy, Paste

Tags: windows-10, audio, macros, autohotkey, clipboard

I have autohotkey installed in my windows 10. How can I have it "beep" or make a sound whenever I Cut, Copy or paste something.

I'm working on a huge record which involves cutting-copying-pasting data around. The problem is sometimes when I copy text, then paste it, the previous data is pasted instead of the new data. It's because sometimes I hit a different button (instead of Ctrl+C Ctrl+X), or maybe the keyboard button was lightly pressed, etc)

So now, I want to make sure that it's already copied or cut or pasted, so I want to hear a sound every time it does new data in the clipboard is really there.

Comment: Sounds like what you want was to see the state of the clipboard

Answer (score 3):

```
#Persistent            ; keeps a script permanently running

    OnClipboardChange: ; is launched automatically whenever the content of the clipboard changes
time_copied :=""
time_copied :=  A_TickCount
; SoundBeep            ; Play the default pitch and duration.
SoundBeep, 750, 500    ; Play a higher pitch for half a second
If (A_EventInfo = 1)   ; the clipboard contains text or files copied
{
    If (DllCall("IsClipboardFormatAvailable", "uint", 15))  ; the clipboard contains file(s)
        ToolTip, file(s) copied
    else
        ToolTip, text copied
}
else
If (A_EventInfo = 2)   ; the clipboard contains images
    ToolTip, image(s) copied
Sleep 1000
ToolTip
return

; ctrl+v for pasting
~^v::   
    SoundBeep
    time_since_copied := (A_TickCount - time_copied)
    time_since_copied /= 1000
    ToolTip, pasted`ncopied: %time_since_copied% seconds ago
    Sleep, 1500
    ToolTip
return
```

For details see [OnClipboardChange](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/OnClipboardChange.htm)

Comment: to show as tray msg: https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/TrayTip.htm

Comment: now, is there a way to execute only on copy, not on cut?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
~^x::
~^c::
~^v::
SoundBeep
```

Put it in a file with the `ahk` extension (e.g. `ClipBeep.ahk`) and double-click it. Whenever you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> it will sound a short beep. Exit the script (right-click on the "H" icon that appears in your notification area at the bottom-right of the screen and select "Exit") to make it stop.

If you want this to always be in effect, I suggest you set it to run at startup.

Comment: I put curly braces around `SoundBeep` to make this work in version 2 of AutoHotkey, though there may be a better way to do that (I'm an AutoHotkey novice).

Answer (score 0):

Use [PowerPro](http://powerpro.cresadu.com/) freeware utility - it has an option to assign different sound to different events (including clipboard ones which you want).

It has a graphical user interface to do it and many-many other very-very useful things.

(I use it more than 10 years and I don't imagine how to work without its help.)

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate sounds when Copy or Paste you need to disable the "Provide feedback with sound" option.

In MS Word click on File --> Options --> Easy of Access --> uncheck the "Provide feedback with sound" option.

I finally got rid of those annoying noises.

[image]